# Apple devices don't click on link on touch, only make selected. How to solve?

Tags: html, css, touch

My website is

```
http://getairmax.ru/
```

(language is Russian)

When I try to use Apple IPad or IPhone browser, it's not clicking, only hovering

Please, help me to make open a link when I touch on apple device.

Comment: How to you expect us to resolve your issue without any code...?

Comment: I wrote the link to help. Cuz I can not put all the page code. I don't know what code is using. Help me please

Comment: Can you create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) example where the problem still occurs? It might also help you to narrow down the problem.

Comment: I can not put, because I don't know what the part of code I need.
Please, open the link and try to help me to find the solution for Apple devices

Comment: First you cannot hover on a phone or tablet since there is no such thing as a mouseover. I tested this on my iPad and when I click a photo of a shoe or a blue link below it then I see details about the shoe so don't know what your problem is.

Comment: Thank you a lot, but there'sa problem when my useras are yousing the site. they can not touch on the item. it doesn't work. Safari last browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For apple devices I use this `jquery` code:

```
$('your selector').on('click touchstart',function(){
//your code
});
```

Comment: You are my god! Thankk you!